# I am getting Error 424 while trying to save a file using Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

Here is the statement -

`pasteBook.SaveAs fn:=folderName & "\Excels\" & fn & " " & Format(DateTime.Now(), "MM-dd-yyy"), FileFormat:=51`

Note - `pasteBook` is defined to be as the current `ThisWorkbook`. I keep getting the following message box

```
Run-time eror '424':
Object required
```

Comment: can you paste more code, did you try calling ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: 1) Is your path correct?  Debug.print to test
2) What is pasteBook?  Again, as user2348184 suggested, please post your code in blocks, or complete codes

Comment: As suggested above, setting pasteBook to thisworkbook will resolve the issue. Also need to change `fn:=` to `FileName:=`

Comment: Thanks guys! Issue has been resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="fred"
Not

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fn:="fred"

If you're usingh named arguments to a function they have to be the right names!